# Do you need to use, and can you use, perform() and performAndWait() inside performBackgroundTask()?

Tags: swift, core-data

If I am performing CoreData operations (delete local persistent data, fetch new data from online, save to persistent store) inside a `storeContainer.performBackgroundTask() { context in ... }` block,

1) Do I NEED to use `context.perform() { }` inside this to ensure it is thread safe?

2) CAN I use `context.performAndWait() { }` for part or all of the function inside the curly brackets if I wish to ensure, for example, deletion occurs before downloading and re-saving?

I'm having user crashes associated with CoreData saving which don't appear on testing. I suspect I am failing to understand something about CoreData. I haven't managed to find the answer to this question elsewhere in tutorials or StackOverflow despite searching for ages!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The main job of **performBackgroundTask** is to create an appropriate background context and call that context on respective queue. You don't need to use "perform" again to switch to private queue.
2. **performAndWait** is useful when ever you are on main queue but context is  private and you want to finish the database update to move forward(similar cases). You don't need to call **performAndWait** inside **perform** because code inside **perform** executes serially. There is no harm in using though.

Comment: @AhmadF Fixed the typo. It should be "want".